# Youtube videos failed to upload after upgrading to xcode7

Tags: ios, youtube, gdata

```
- (void)uploadTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
   finishedWithEntry:(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)videoEntry
               error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ticket");

    UIButton *uploadButton = (UIButton *)[backgroundImage viewWithTag:10];
    UIButton   *cancleButton = (UIButton *)[backgroundImage viewWithTag:20];
    if (error == nil)
    {
        // tell the user that the add worked


        NSLog(@"Video Successfully Uploaded to Youtube");

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSNumber *uploadedToYouTube = [defaults objectForKey:@"uploadedToYouTube"];
        if(nil == uploadedToYouTube)
        {
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"uploadedToYouTube"];
            [defaults synchronize];
        }

        NSNumber *userOpenedYoutubeView = [defaults objectForKey:@"userOpenedYoutubeToUnlockTheme"];
        if(nil != userOpenedYoutubeView)
        {
            // [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"Unlock_Theme"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"Unlock_Theme"];
            [defaults synchronize];

            UIAlertView *alrtView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats...!" message:@"Your new theme is Unlocked" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alrtView show];
            [alrtView release];

             [self removeFromSuperview];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alrtView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success...!" message:@"Your Video is successfully uploaded to Youtube" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alrtView show];
            [alrtView release];

            [self removeFromSuperview];
        }

    }
    else {



        NSLog(@"Fails to upload Video to Youtube");

        UIAlertView *alrtView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Fails to upload video to Youtube. Please try again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alrtView show];
        [alrtView release];

    }

    mProgressView . hidden = YES;
    uploadButton . hidden = NO;
    cancleButton . enabled = YES;

    [mProgressView setProgress: 0.0];

    [self setUploadTicket:nil];
}
```

Every time i try to upload it is showing alert message "failed to upload". I don't get why it is showing like that. Before upgrading to Xcode 7 it works fine. Anyone know please help me.

Comment: What is the value of `error`?

Comment: Could be app transport security. Try opting out.